# Calendar Syncing

Tags: data-synchronization, calendar

I have several calendars on my mac laptop, Exchange, Yahoo and Google. I'm having trouble syncing my phone with my laptop all of the sudden. I haven't changed any settings.
The weird thing is certain appointments on my Exchange calendar show up on my phone but not others.
Or I'll move appointments on my laptop but it doesn't sync with my phone.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The calendars on your laptop don't sync with your phone but sync to the originating sources and other devices have to poll and update themselves at regular intervals. Only iCloud and probably exchange calendars do a push sync.

In either case, the problem for you is NOT that the phone is not syncing with the laptop (it never does), but it is not syncing with the originating server (Yahoo, Exchange, Google etc). Try re-adding the calendar on the phone.